# мультиязычный хелп

Tags: html

Есть файл html, который и есть Read Me. Есть необходимость, чтобы пользователь имел возможность переключаться на другие языки. В голову пришел вариант открывать другой html документ с новым языком и закрывать старый. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Открывать где? Десктоп или веб?

Comment: Если нужно открыть одну `html` из другой - сделайте просто ссылку(тег `a`)

Comment: установлена прога и в стартовом меню ссылка на read me. не веб.

Comment: Распишите подробнее, что происходит. Если ссылки/тексты меняются через приложение, опишите подробнее на чем написано приложение, что в нем происходит.

Comment: обычный файл, с описанием команд. Можно сказать, что файл статический. Есть перевод на другой язык. Все именно так как как в вопросе - не более